# What is the structure and meaning of this strange sentence starting with "it needs no prophet"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, expressions, sentence-structure

> It needs no prophet to see that aviation is going to raise some extremely difficult legal problems […]
>   <sub>[Source](http://www.repository.law.indiana.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2424&context=ilj)</sub>

What is the structure and meaning of this sentence?

Comment: Obviously this is not proof reading. I wanna know what this sentence means! What's wrong with this? Proof reading is something I ask you to do to my own writing. Obviously this is not my writing. If this is not appropriate i don't know what is.

Answer (score 1):

> It needs no prophet to see that aviation is going to raise some extremely difficult legal problems.

I find *it needs no prophet* a bit sloppy, but the meaning is clear:

> It is not necessary to have somebody who can predict the future.

Now, what would we need that prophet for? *To see* something.
To see what? *That aviation is going to raise some extremely difficult legal problems*.

So, we have a simple opinion:

> Aviation is going to raise some extremely difficult legal problems.

This is a prediction about something that will happen in the future, but according to the author, it is very clear that this will happen: there is no need for a person who can *see the future*, a *prophet*, to make this prediction.

A common variation is:

> Anyone can see that aviation will raise problems.

Comment: I think the more common or mundane wording would be, "We do not need a prophet to see ..." The wording here, "It needs no ..." seems archaic or excessively formal to me, rather than sloppy, but whatever.